# Disappearing nodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

After attempting to add data that's typed into my textbox (ScanIdBox) and clicking the AddButton, my rootNode seems to disappear, and the TreeView is then blank. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, as I'm new to Windows Forms and TreeViews. What I'm trying to do is add a parentNode if the item's length is 8 and a childNode if the item's length is 9. I don't want the root node to disappear, but want all items that are 8 characters long to be a parent node under the root node and want all other items to be child nodes of the most recently added parent node. How can I accomplish this?

```
public class Nodes
    {
        public TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
        public TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode();
        public TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
    }

    public void Scan_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _boxNumberRepository = new BoxNumberRepository();

        Nodes _rootNode = new Nodes();
        _rootNode.rootNode.Text = "Scan ID";
        BoxAndFileList.Nodes.Add(_rootNode.rootNode);

        Text = "Scan Form";
        AcceptButton = AddButton;
        ScanIdLabel.Text = "Enter Scan ID #";
        AddButton.Text = "Add";
        RemoveButton.Text = "Remove";
    }

    public void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        Nodes _rootNode = new Nodes();
        BoxAndFileList.Nodes.Clear();
        ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;
        var items = new List<string>(_boxNumberRepository.GetAllItems());
        foreach (var boxNumber in items)
            if (boxNumber.Length == 8)
            {
                _rootNode.rootNode.Nodes.Add(boxNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                _rootNode.parentNode.Nodes.Add(boxNumber);
            }
    }

    public void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var boxNumber = ScanIdBox.Text.Trim();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxNumber))
        {
            _boxNumberRepository.AddItem(boxNumber);
            PopulateTreeView();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: figured out why the node was disappearing. I was clearing the nodes in PopulateTreeView. Commented that out and it stuck around. Still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong to add the items. They're still not adding.

EDIT2: This code is now allowing me to add items to the TreeView, but it still deletes the rootNode. I'm not entirely sure that I really need that rootNode, now that I think about it, so I'm not really worried about it.

```
public void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        BoxAndFileList.Nodes.Clear();
        var items = new List<string>(_boxNumberRepository.GetAllItems());
        foreach (var boxNumber in items)
            BoxAndFileList.Nodes.Add(boxNumber);
        ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing in the `PopulateTreeView` method seems to add anything to `BoxAndFileList`. I don't know much about tree view, but maybe put in something similar to `BoxAndFileList.Nodes.Add(_rootNode.rootNode);` (as you have in your `Scan_Form_Load` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping TreeView. It may very well have worked, but I simply added things to a list. The items were to be added sequentially, so it wasn't a big deal. Not a good solution, but it worked and the client was happy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your code to:

```
public void PopulateTreeView()
{
     var items = new List<string>(_boxNumberRepository.GetAllItems());
    foreach (var boxNumber in items)
        BoxAndFileList.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(boxNumber);
    ScanIdBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Note adding to the Parent by using SelectedNode and you do not want to clear the nodes.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line BoxAndFileList.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(boxNumber);
I'm thinking it's because there's no selected node. Should a node be selected for a child to be added to a parent?

Comment: Or you must go and find/pick the Parent node to add to. But yes you must add a child to the parent. So you can select the node or find the parent you want to add to and _parent.Nodes.add.(boxNumber).